# Automating the creation of service principal in Azure in a customer account

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Here is a scenario. I have a SaaS product that needs to make api calls to customer's Azure cloud account. I understand a service principal can be created on the customer's AZ account, and if I have the credentials(app id, password, etc), I can make calls using that user/principal based on the permissions to that principal. One way is that customer creates it for my product, then comes to my product portal(web ui) and punches in this information which my SaaS product can then store securely in vault and use it.

Is there a better way to achieve the creation of the principal? For example via application manifest or something and then also be able to get a Event grid notification or something with the app/principal's creds to a webhook url endpoint?

Basically, I want this to be as automated as possible but cannot think of a way if it is even possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally if you are writing a multi-tenant application, you will set up your app registration as multi-tenant, and you will call the "common" endpoint for all users to log in.
when the admin from a different tenant logs into your application, if set up properly, a consent window will appear and when they consent, the Service principal will automatically be created in their tenant.
please see here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-convert-app-to-be-multi-tenant#understand-user-and-admin-consent

Comment: Yes, I found this info from friend, exactly what I am doing. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: I almost got it working but suddenly running into a strange login issue. Do you have any thoughts on that. Pasting my other question's link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63226826/azure-login-for-tenant-failing-for-az-app-principal-with-no-subscription-found-m